acl for yarn capacity scheduler is not working
I have a cluster hadoop (1 master 1 slave) and I divided the resources into 2 queue: a and b then i use Acls to grant permissions to user1 can submit queue a, user2 can use queue b. I try run [user2@master ~]$spark-shell --master yarn cluster --queue a then it worked.
[user2@master ~]$spark-shell --master yarn cluster --queue a
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/09/12 15:00:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
24/09/12 15:00:45 WARN SparkConf: Note that spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone/kubernetes and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
24/09/12 15:00:47 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
Spark context Web UI available at http://master:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1726127970185_0001).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.5.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.18 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_202)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>


this is my yarn-site.xml:
<configuration>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>xxx.xx.xx.90</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>8</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>16384</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>16384</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
               
  <property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
      <value>xxx.xx.xx.90:31189</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>xxx.xx.xx.90:8032</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
      <value>/app/tmp</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
      <value>/app/tmp</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.admin.acl</name>
    <value>hadoop</value>
  </property>
  
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
  </property>

</configuration>

this is capacity-scheduler.xml:
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
      Maximum number of applications that can be pending and running.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>0.01</value>
    <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run 
      application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
      applications.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator</value>
    <description>
      The ResourceCalculator implementation to be used to compare 
      Resources in the scheduler.
      The default i.e. DefaultResourceCalculator only uses Memory while
      DominantResourceCalculator uses dominant-resource to compare 
      multi-dimensional resources such as Memory, CPU etc.
    </description>
  </property>
  
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.user.max-parallel-apps</name>
    <value>100</value>
    <description>
      Maximum number of applications that can be running.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
    <value>a,b</value>
    <description>The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.a.capacity</name>
    <value>40</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.b.capacity</name>
    <value>60</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.a.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>40</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.b.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>60</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.a.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.b.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>
  
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.a.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>user1</value>
  </property>
     
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.a.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>user1</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can administer jobs on the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.b.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>user2</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can submit jobs to the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>
  
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.b.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>user2</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can administer jobs on the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

</configuration>

I was setup them in master and coppy in salve.
any help me?
